# How to scale any object to a certain size by the python script?

Tags: python, scripting, scale

What code will make it possible to scale any object to a certain size, reading the maximum coordinates of the object's vertices along each of the axes (x, y, z)?

I have an objects (parts of different bodies, weapons and e.t.c.), which I want to randomly generate in new united object in different variations. I need to do this accurately so that there are no empty spaces between parts of objects in such a way, that the boundaries of these maximum vertices create a parallelogram.

Then I need to scale that parallelogram to the dimensions (not a real parallelogram, the mesh should remain the same in shape, just the scale should coincide with the boundaries of the already created parallelograms, as in the picture).

Unfortunately, I don't know ANYTHING about programming in python, so I would be very happy, if someone help me!

[image: This is an example of how far objects should be scaled]

Comment: First you need to define *"size"* - do you want to scale the object, so it has given height in z dimension? Or do you want it to scale to be x% of original size, e.g. double it's height and other dimensions?

Comment: I want the boundaries of this object to clearly coincide in size with the boundaries of the parallelogram, that is, all coordinates along the x, y and z-axes.

Comment: Surely then we're talking rectangles, a special case of a [parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram)  Sounds like simply need to match dimensions `target.dimensions = source.dimensions`